# Getting the List of registered devices from fcm for my app

Tags: firebase, token, store, messaging

I am using fcm. I have a android app using firebase console to push notifications in production. Now I want to write my own app server to send notifications to all the registered users. How do I get the the tokens for all the registered devices into my new app server ?

Answer (score 0):

Just send the notification to the topic "all" :

```
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array (
            'to' => "/topics/all", 
            'notification' => array (
                    "title" => "TITLE",
                    "body" => "NOTIFICATION TEXT"
            )
    );

    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key='.$server_key, // your server key
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    echo $result;
    curl_close ( $ch );
```

I found this topic by default in my console.. I think it's the same for everyone

Comment: I am using Device registration tokens to send the message and not by "topic".

Comment: _"..to send notifications to all the registered users."_ ... Anyway, you can get the device token and put it in a db